# how to disable a submit button if text_field is empty in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am new to ROR. I just want to know is it possible to disable a submit tag button if the text_field is empty.??

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it with jquery like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/utasar/1/edit)**

```
if($('#text_field').val() ==  "") 
   $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', true);

$('#text_field').keyup(function(){
    if($('#text_field').val() !=  "") 
         $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', false);    
    else
         $('#submitButtonId').attr('disabled', true);   
});
```

For latest version of jQuery you may need to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of attr() to set the disabled property of the element.

```
if($('#text_field').val() ==  "") 
   $('#submitButtonId').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: hi, thanks, its working in the live demo. Where shall i give the form id in this script? bcz its not working into my form. I think should need to give the form id to get that works. Thanks

Comment: Do you still need help as you accepted and might have solved the form id confusion ?

Comment: This is when I type something it enables. What if my button type is number?

Answer (score 1):

Typically it's done through validations, so the button stays active but the form gets validation errors and doesn't save.
In your model you would add:

```
validates_presence_of :some_field, :some_other_field
```

If you want to do it anyway, you would use javascript to accomplish it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, the problem is the button call the sql stored procedure directly. So it doesn't consider the normal validations we do in MODEL. That's why i came into jquery to enable and disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that

```
$(function(){

     var val = $('#text_field').val();
     if(val == ''){
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
     }
});
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/G6BJN/)